# How do I style a ui selectmenu widget button with selected text being a different color?

Tags: user-interface, widget

I have been trying to style the main heading button of a created selectmenu widget that was created via the widget factory process. I would like to change the button color or font size using the elements id and not the via the static .ui-selectmenu-button class. I have been searching and trying all sorts of code for days. If anyone can help me it would be greatly appreciated my code follows:

```
<style>
.ui-selectmenu-button {font-size:9pt; color:red; height:30px; width:136px !important;}
.options-menu {font-size:10pt; width:150px;}
.raps-hide-option {display:none;}
.myclass {font-size:12pt;height:30px; color:green; width:136px !important;}
</style>

<script>
$(function () {
   /* Make the widget object for my select menu */
   $.widget( "custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
      _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
        var li = $( "<li>", { text: item.label } );
        if ( item.disabled ) {
          // li.addClass( "ui-state-disabled" );
          li.addClass( "raps-hide-option" );
        };
        $( "<span>", {
          style: item.element.attr( "data-style" ),
          "class": "ui-icon " + item.element.attr( "data-class" )
        })
          .appendTo( li );

        return li.appendTo( ul );
      }
    });
   /* Bind the created select menu object to my #our-details id */
   $( "#our-details" ).iconselectmenu(
    {
    create: function( event, ui ) {this.value="Our Details"; $( "#our-details" ).iconselectmenu("refresh");},           
    change: function( event, ui ) { this.value="Our Details"; $( "#our-details" ).iconselectmenu("refresh");}
        }
    ).iconselectmenu( "menuWidget" ).addClass( "ui-menu-icons options-menu" );
   /* this is where i try to change the font size or color */
   $( "#our-details" ).addClass("myclass");
});
</script>
```

Html follows:

```
<body>
<select id="our-details">
    <option value="Our Details" disabled="disabled" data-class="ui-icon-carat-2-n-s">Contact Details</option>
    <option value="Contact Us" data-class="ui-icon-mail-closed">Contact Us</option>
    <option id="abou_02" value="Office Location" data-class="ui-icon-home">Our Location</option>
</select>
</body>
```

my fiddle code:
http://jsfiddle.net/rotsen49/xkgdh68v/13/